# reload data from core data in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fetch data from core data with table view cells, but when the data is reloaded each item in the cell take separate cells, I hope you understand what I mean.

this is the code that I think it has an error

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //1
        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ShopList")

        //3
        do {
            let results =
                try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            people = results as! [NSManagedObject]

            let results2 =
                try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            ids = results2 as! [NSManagedObject]


        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! itemsList


        let shopList = people[indexPath.row]
        cell.items!.text = shopList.valueForKey("name") as? String

        let shopList2 = ids[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemsId!.text = shopList2.valueForKey("logo") as? String



        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is error?

Comment: I have 2 items in each cell, when I fetch the data the 2 items in the cell reloaded in separate cells, each item takes one cell instead of 2 items in one cell

Comment: Please paste code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath..` method

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Why are you fetching in two separate arrays when they contain the same data?

Comment: can you make an answer if you think that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this if problem still exists please add code for numberOfRowsInSection in question

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            //1
            let appDelegate =
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

            //2
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ShopList")

            //3
            do {
                let results =
                    try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                people = results as! [NSManagedObject]


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! itemsList

            let shopList = people[indexPath.row]
            cell.items!.text = shopList.valueForKey("name") as? String
            cell.itemsId!.text = shopList.valueForKey("logo") as? String

            return cell
        }
```